# Extracting numeric character of length (1|2) from character list

Tags: r, regex

I am scraping PDFs for data and am trying to search for a numeric character (1:9) that is either of length 1 or 2. Unfortunately the value I am after changes position across the PDFs so I cannot simply call the index of the value and assign it to a variable.

I have tried many regex functions and can get numbers out of the list, but cannot seem to implement the argument to only pull numbers of the specific length.

```
# Data comes in as a long string
Test<-("82026-424 82026-424 1 CSX10 Store Room 75.74 75.74")

# Seperate data into individual pieces with str_split
Split_Test<-str_split(Test[1],"\\s+")

# We can easily unlist it with the following code (Not sure if needed)
Test_Unlisted<-unlist(Split_Test)

> Test_Unlisted
[1] "82026-424" "82026-424" "1"         "CSX10"     "Store"     "Room"      
[8] "75.74" "75.74"
```

My desired outcome would be to get the "1" out of the character list, and then if the value was "20" also be able to recognize that.

The best logic I can think of in code exists below, but this does not work.:

```
Test_Final<-str_match(Test_Unlisted, "\\d|\\d\\d")
```

Using this code I can grab anything of length=1, but it is not guaranteed to be a character:

```
Test_Final<-which(sapply(Test_Unlisted, nchar)==1)
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @missuse That unfortunately gave a similar result as the str_match() argument described above.  It seems to pull two numbers anywhere it can, as in it breaks the 82026-424 into "82" "02" "6" "42"...etc. Best case scenario we only pull the true length 1 or 2 numbers/characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
Test<-("82026-424 82026-424 1 CSX10 Store Room 75.74 75.74, 20")
regmatches(Test, gregexpr("\\b(?<!\\d\\.)\\d{1,2}\\b(?!\\.\\d)", Test, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [regex demo](https://ideone.com/oiSiC2) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FP55Im/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\d\.)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a digit and a dot
- `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\.\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a dot and a digit.

Note that due to the lookarounds used in the pattern, the regex should be passed to the PCRE regex engine, hence the `perl=TRUE` argument is required.

With `stringr` that is ICU regex engine powered, you may use

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(Test, "\\b(?<!\\d\\.)\\d{1,2}\\b(?!\\.\\d)")
```

Comment: Very nice, I don't think I can write regex that well so thank you.

Comment: It can be shortened a bit, I updated the answe and added the explanation.